# Access db data type error

Tags: javascript, sql, ms-access

I'm trying to insert a row into an access database (mdb, access 2000 AFAIK) as follows:

```
conn.execute("INSERT INTO entries (userCol,typeCol,numitems,entrytime,worktime) VALUES ('mattk','Item 1',4,1339361723424,1339361723424)")
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
Message: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
```

The variable conn is an adodb connection object. It's declared and initialised in javascript as follows:

```
var conn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
conn.open('Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=' + source + ';User Id=admin;Password=;');
```

I've confirmed the following data types:

```
userCol: text
typeCol: text
numitems: integer
entrytime: long
worktime: long
```

I just can't fathom what could be causing this. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Just to add to the `This is what is wrong` answers, here is something that might actually help `resolve` the issue ;)  `LONG` is only 4 bytes in size, the size of normal 32 bit system's INT.  `DOUBLE` is an 8 byte value, and should be able to hold the values you need, and `DECIMAL` is up to 12 bytes which can also hold what you want.  There isn't, afaik, an 8 byte integer data type in MS-Access 2000.  Of the above two options I'd probably use `DOUBLE` for representing large whole numbers, but I think `DECIMAL` is intended for this really.

Comment: Indeed, I had assumed that the size of a long would be the same as in other implementations. Otherwise, why call it a long? More fool me, haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MS-Access Long data type can hold values from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 (signed).

You're trying to insert too big numbers.

Comment: I had assumed the limits would be the same as in other languages. ick. Thanks for this. Seeing as you were first, I'll tick your answer as soon as I can (2 minutes or so).

Answer (score 2):

You can see the data types for db engines in [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp).

According to this page you are trying to assign too big values for long fields. You should choose a more suitable type for those fields.

Answer (score 1):

The rang of an LONG integer value in MS-Access is – 2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.  Your values are outside of this range.